# Variable Declarations in a With Block

Tags: javascript, scope, lexical-scope

I preface this by saying I know that use of `with` is highly discouraged, and I don't intend on using it either. I'm just curious about learning how it works (I'm trying to figure out scope in javascript).

If I have some code like this:

```
function foo(obj) {
    with (obj) {
        b = 2;
    }
}

var o1 = {
    a: "something"
};

foo( o1 );
console.log(o1.b) // This outputs undefined (makes sense)
console.log(b) // This outputs 2 (makes sense)
```

However, if I change foo to something like this:

```
function foo(obj) {
    with (obj) {
        var b = 2; // I use var b instead of b
    }
}
```

When I pass in o1 to foo, again, o1 has no attribute b. Why is this? I thought using `var` would declare b inside the scope of obj, so the attribute would be created inside o1 instead of in the global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` declarations are hoisted. So what you are executing is equivalent to

```
function foo(obj) {
    var b;
    with (obj) {
        b = 2;
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter that the declaration is inside a `with` block. [§9.2.12](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) describes what happens when the function body is evaluated. In step 11/12, all variable declarations are collected. A `with` statement simply "forwards" all the declarations inside of it ([see spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-with-statement-static-semantics-vardeclarednames)).

Answer (score 1):

Variable declarations (using `var`) do not respect block scope and instead are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the top of the scope. As far as the compiler/interpreter is concerned, your code is actually:

```
function foo(obj) {
    var b = undefined;
    with (obj) {
        b = 2;
    }
}
```